# start jquery function on a specific scroll level

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I tried out a jquery plugin for fancy pie charts http://codepen.io/githiro/pen/ICfFE

I implemented it to this site: http://digi.hkettelhut.de/
But now I don't want it to animate at the page load but on the sight of the section #general. I am not into jquery, that's why I couldn't figure out how to handle this problem by myself.

I already tried to implement a if clause:

```
 $(function(){
if ($("body").scrollTop() > (window.innerHeight - 5)) {
  $("#gender").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "männlich", value: 120,  color: "#0478c6" },
    { title: "weiblich", value:  80,  color: "#FF00FF" },
  ]);

  $("#age").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "19", value:  20,  color: "#0478c6" },
    { title: "20", value:  80,  color: "#FF00FF" },
    { title: "21", value:  35,  color: "#0c4883" },
    { title: "22", value:  65,  color: "#7e0a7e" },
  ]);

  $("#country").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "Deutschland", value: 165,  color: "#0478c6" },
    { title: "England", value:  20,  color: "#FF00FF" },
    { title: "Frankreich", value:  15,  color: "#0c4883" },
  ]);
 }
});
```

Comment: jQuery scrollTop can solve your problem. But, I suggest you to put some code to show where exactly you are struck

Comment: almost forgot, sorry. edited ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside of a scroll event handler and then check if the scrollTop of the body is greater than the offset of the element you are looking for.

```
$(function () {
  $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > $(/*element you are looking for*/).offset().top) {
      // Draw pie chart
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Do I have to put it around the whole thing, around the excerpt or into the excerpt? Because neither of this tries worked for me. :\

Comment: Instead of doing `$('body').on(...);`, do `$(window).on(...);` My apologies. I'll edit the answer. That should work.

Comment: little update: had also to change the second 'body' into window, to get it to work in all browsers. 'body' only worked on chrome for me. 'html,body' only in IE and FF. window works for all just fine!